не могу передать трехзначное число в регистр
Эмулятор МП КР580BM80 , архитектура intel 8080
Никак не получается передать никакое трехзначное число, первая цифра съедается (пример: пытаюсь передать 255 - идет 55), буквами пробовал, просто фиксирует буквы.
В первый раз каким-то образом получилось, в этот - никак.
Передаю следующим образом:
ORG 800
MVI A, 255
HLT 

Как решить вопрос?

Хм... А в прошлой теме о чём речь шла в связи c 255?

Может этот ассемблер считает, что все числа д.б. шестнадцатиричными?

@MBo там был цикл на 255 повторов, и код прерывался после 55 итераций, так как эмулятор при вводе 255 читал только 55. Там мне посоветовали вместо 255 написать FF и это каким-то образом сработало, код выполнился. Я перешёл к следующему заданию, попытался сделать тоже самое - не работает. Снова загрузил прошлый код - он тоже снова не работает

@avp я пробовал передавать ff, фиксирует буквы, а не числа в 10-ой. Дальше с буквами по коду взаимодействие не идет, не работает, как надо. Я могу отредактировать и написать, что пытаюсь сделать в целом, но ответ на заданный тут вопрос о том, возможно ли передать это в принципе мне тоже крайне важен

Какая-то документация на этот ассемблер и эмулятор КР580BM80 у вас есть?

Пробуйте FFH вместо 255

@avp к сожалению нет, это лабораторная работа, в наличии только методические указания, в которых примеры каких-то базовых программ, но и там задавались только однозначные числа. Ну и список команд ещё есть, но там нужного тоже нет

@AlexanderPetrov пробовал, не работает, выдает ошибку

Так и пишет: "Ошибка"? Или всё же какое-то конкретное сообщение?
